# Latex error: File tgtermes.sty not found

Tags: packages, texlive, tex-core, mac

I installed BasicTex.pkg in OS X to generate pdf file of a sphinx documentation. When I ran `make latexpdf`, it throws the error `LaTeX Error: File` tgtermes.sty' not found`.

I tried to install it using `tlmgr` by running `tlgmr install tgtermes` to install it, but it throws this error: `tlmgr install: package tgtermes not present in repository`.

Any help on this regard will be useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The texlive package containing `tgtermes.sty` is `tex-gyre`:

```
$ tlmgr info tgtermes.sty
tlmgr: cannot find package tgtermes.sty, searching for other matches:

Packages containing `tgtermes.sty' in their title/description:

Packages containing files matching `tgtermes.sty':
tex-gyre:
        texmf-dist/tex/latex/tex-gyre/tgtermes.sty
```